# Single Sign-On Across Multiple Domains

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on

I am currently in the process of building a Single Sign-On system to manage user credentials across multiple of my domains using node and express. They are currently all subdomains of my primary domain however that won't always be that case, hence I can't use domain-wide cookies.

Schematic looks something like this, using a forum and shop as an example:

```
 Forum User Wants To Use     |    Shop User Wants To Use    |    My Single Sign-On Service
    forum.mydomain.com       |      shop.mydomain.com       |       auth.mydomain.com
```

I would like a user visiting the forum or shop to be able to register/login at auth.mydomain.com and then be able to access all sites.

I have seen quite a few approaches to this from 5-6 years ago however a lot have been deprecated or are advised not to be used. What is the most secure way of achieving this? Many sources have pointed me toward OAuth 2.0, what would be the current industry standard method?

Edit: Added API flow diagram.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure that you forgot to mention your api layer.  Do you want to manage the security in your sites and apis or just the login in your multiple sites?

Comment: @JRichardsz edited to include a diagram of what I think the flow should look like, does this help?

Comment: Diagram helps a lot. Are your sites monolithics or web modules with apis/microservices? If your sites are monoliths and your requirement is just sso, you don't need oauth. But if you have websites with current frameworks like angular, react, vue +  your backend is modularized in apis or microsercices + you have complex roles behaviors for your users in each website, **oauth2** is for you. What is your case?